# Trying to relate tables in MySQL and Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database

I'm having problems relating some tables, I have the client table with the fields ("name, age and gender") and another table called personal_documents with the fields "cpf, rg, etc ...), I tried the relationship of personal_documents belongs_to client but when i search for client only the fields of client ("name, age and gender) and "personal_documents_id" appear, the fields for personal documents ("cpf, rg, etc...) should also appear too, thanks for the help!

***Code:***

*In client model:*

```
has_one :personal_documents
```

*in personal_documents model:*

```
belongs_to :client
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rails generate model Client 
inside migration file you create as follow

```
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :clients do |t|
      t.string     :user_kind
      # your other field here
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

rails generate model PersonalDocument
inside migration file you create as follow

```
class CreatePersonalDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :personal_documents do |t|
      # this is the one that relate personal document
      # to client
      t.references :client, index: true
      t.string :rg_front
      # other field
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

inside model you can declare as follow

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  # please note personal_document in singular
  has_one :personal_document, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :personal_document, allow_destroy: :true

  # now you can do some like above for disponibility, personal_document_legal, bank_information
end

class PersonalDocument < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
end
```

inside your controller you declare as follow

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def barang_params
    params.require(:client).permit(
      :user_kind,
      personal_document_attributes: [
        :id,
        :rg_front, 
        :rg_back, 
        :cpf, 
        :cnh_front, 
        :cnh_back, 
        :bank_card_front, 
        :address_proof, 
        :profile_picture
      ]
      # this from your other question, and I think it's already correct
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To access `personal_documents` of client

```
Client.find(1).personal_documents.cpf
```

To access client of `personal_documents`

```
PersonalDocument.find(id).client.name
```

both

```
document = PersonalDocument.find(id)
client = document.client

or

client = Client.find(1)
document = client.personal_documents


document.cpf
client.name
```

additionaly change `:has_one` to singular `personal_document`

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer, but I still have doubts about, how would I do to be able to register this client with all the data in the controller for example? what would the params and permit parameters look like?

Comment: you can use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods) for creating and updating the client and association